# How do I install SDL Ball?

Tags: software-installation, games

I've enjoyed 100's of hours replaying SDL Ball. A Microsoft chat tech made my computer unusable and I had to have Ubuntu reinstalled. Now SDL Ball is no longer on the list of downloadable games.

I think it is far and away the best game on Linux. Please relist it.

Comment: Thank you, but I need more instruction....got to "Processing triggers for  libc-bin ..." and tried "y" and "run" to answer "j@j -desktop:@~$

Answer (score 1):

To install this game open a Terminal and copy and paste the following into it:

```
sudo apt-get install sdl-ball
```

Below is this game running on Xenial Xerus after following these instructions:

[image]

May you have many more productive hours playing this :).

Comment: Thanks @andrew.46 but i still need help,  i don'tt know if m last "Add C' got to you so... I got to "j@j-desktop:~$" and tried "y"  "run", "go"and "add"???.

Comment: Before i get your answer, i will have logged out of Linux. Should I start again from the beginning or can I somehow pick up at "j@j-desktop:$"?

Comment: THANK YOU @andrew.46.  I looked on 'Search your computer' and it is there/here again.